# RBLPAPI options

Tags: r, blpapi, rblpapi

I am playing around with the Rblpapi package, but am not having any joy setting the periodicity of the downloaded data

```
opt <- c("periodictySelection" = "WEEKLY")
SPX <- bdh("SPX Index","PX_Last", start.date=Sys.Date()-30, include.non.trading.days = FALSE, options=opt
```

i also tried:

```
opt <- c("per" = "cw")
```

as per the excel api

However, I keep getting an error:
Error: Sub-element '(null)' does not exist.

I cant see any tips in the help files.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `c("periodictySelection", "WEEKLY")`?

Comment: absolutely right. fixing  the obvious mistake i see: Error: Request options must be named.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a simple spelling mistake in the original post: `opt <- c("periodictySelection" = "WEEKLY")` has `periodicitySelection` misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
opt <- c("periodicitySelection"="WEEKLY")
```

did the trick

Comment: How is that different from what you did before?

Comment: Please don't write only code, explain it, so the future readers can learn from your answer.